# How to get 4 digit numbers after decimal including before decimal also in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a data that is`101.32650000` and I want to get `101.3265` only ... I tried using right function, but the disadvantage is that digits before decimal can vary.

Comment: `Select cast(101.32650000 AS decimal(18,4))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using `cast` with `decimal` and scale of 4.  Something like:

```
select cast(101.32650000 as decimal(10,4));
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/507e0/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
cast(col_name as decimal(28,4)) as col_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(101.32650000 AS DECIMAL(10,4));
```